# ASP.NET Web Tools 2012.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm attempting to create a project in Visual Studio 2012 Express Web. Even after installing this update I still get a failure message when trying to create a new project/website. Including the ones that are listed in this image.

I understand this isn't a programming question, but feel it's useful to those using this platform for development and may have come across the same issue. Am I missing something?

[image: Installed Screenshot]

EDIT

Error Message.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Your NuGet add-on is corrupt reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I uninstalled it, re-installed it and rebooted my pc - I'm getting the same error..?

Comment: My bad, after the reboot it kicked in, put your comment in an answer and I will accept it!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the screenshot provided the Visual Studio 2012 NuGet add-on was corrupt.  The solution is to reinstall the add-on then restart Visual Studio.  You might need also need to reboot the computer.

Comment: I would appreciate feedback on how to approve this answer.  However, I suspect it’s due to revenge downvoting, since more than one of my answers got downvoted.  It’s absolutely ridiculous that this answer received a downvote